# google.com crawl errors to non-existent urls

Tags: google-search-console

Google webmasters tools has a bunch crawl errors (404) for urls to non-existent pages on my site. I never link to these  urls. How can I solve this problem ... it is affecting my adwords campaign? I tried to do a 302 redirect, but that did not work.

Comment: Give us one example of 404 url

Comment: Did you solve this issue?